# Create a new mixin in sling

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I am having trouble create a new custom type to the jackrabbit in apache sling using the below code. This worked fine straight on Jackrabbit but not on Apache Sling. Am I doing this correctly for sling? Thanks

The following code gives me a "javax.jcr.InvalidItemStateException: Conflict". I am using a standalone sling and am the only user so there is definitely no conflict.

```
Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:8080/server");

Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));

NamespaceRegistry registry = session.getWorkspace().getNamespaceRegistry();
registry.registerNamespace("my", "http://my.com/v1.0");

CndImporter.registerNodeTypes(new FileReader("C:\\test.cnd"), session);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Sling, you can avoid all this by putting your CND file in an OSGi bundle (where your java code should reside anyway), with a header that tells Sling where to find it.

Your node types will then be registered automatically when your bundle is activated. For an example of this see the [event.cnd](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-event/blob/master/src/main/resources/SLING-INF/nodetypes/event.cnd) file which is declared in a Sling-Nodetypes bundle header that's set in that module's [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-event/blob/master/pom.xml) (or in any other way if you're not using Maven).

Note also that you shouldn't need JcrUtils.getRepository in Sling anyway, the right way to get a repository is via the SlingRepository OSGi service, which takes care of repository login and configuration in a consistent way for all your Sling components. You can get the repository via a @Reference to a SlingRepository in java code, or get a JCR Session from the Resource that Sling provides to request handlers like servlets and scripts. The [Slingbucks sample](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/samples/slingbucks/) uses both mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDocs for [InvalidItemStateException](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/InvalidItemStateException.html) offer this clue:

> Exception thrown by the write methods of Node and Property and by save
>   and refresh if an attempted change would conflict with a change to the
>   persistent workspace made through another Session. Also thrown by
>   methods of Node and Property if that object represents an item that
>   has been removed from the workspace.

Are you sure that you don't have any old sessions still running, perhaps is a daemon process that hasn't been shut down properly?